# Flutter - creating lists with different types - example (i) => i % 6 == 0 ?

Tags: dart, flutter

New to Flutter and Dart, can anyone explain how this loop works, or what its called so I can search for it, its unlike any loop I have ever seen.

```
new List<ListItem>.generate(
      10,
      (i) => i % 6 == 0
          ? new HeadingItem("Heading $i")
          : new MessageItem("Sender $i", "Message body $i"),
    ),
```

I know that will create 10 items, and every 6th item will be a heading.
But I can't for the life of me step through it.

[Google - Flutter page](https://flutter.io/cookbook/lists/mixed-list/)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a loop. It's just the invocation of a named constructor (`generate`) of the class `List`.

It creates a new `List` of length 10, and calls the function passed as 2nd parameter for every value from 0 to length -1.

See also https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List/List.generate.html

Comment: But there's a loop inside the constructor

Comment: Sure. The Dartdoc site I linked to above shows the `for` loop used to generate the content of the new list.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path, I am more noob than I thought.

Comment: :D no worries. If a lot is new it's easy to get confused. Just ask if you're stuck.